# Android sdkmanager available packages

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

Is there a way to list the whole name of a package so I can install it.  If I do a `sdkmanager --list`, I get a sample of the following:

```
  system-images;a...ult;armeabi-v7a | 4            | ARM EABI v7a System Image        
  system-images;a...-10;default;x86 | 4            | Intel x86 Atom System Image      
  system-images;a...pis;armeabi-v7a | 5            | Google APIs ARM EABI v7a Syste...
  system-images;a...google_apis;x86 | 5            | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom Sys...
  system-images;a...ult;armeabi-v7a | 2            | ARM EABI v7a System Image        
  system-images;a...ult;armeabi-v7a | 4            | ARM EABI v7a System Image        
  system-images;a...15;default;mips | 1            | MIPS System Image                
  system-images;a...-15;default;x86 | 4            | Intel x86 Atom System Image      
  system-images;a...pis;armeabi-v7a | 5            | Google APIs ARM EABI v7a Syste...
  system-images;a...google_apis;x86 | 5            | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom Sys...
  system-images;a...ult;armeabi-v7a | 4            | ARM EABI v7a System Image        
  system-images;a...16;default;mips | 1            | MIPS System Image                
  system-images;a...-16;default;x86 | 5            | Intel x86 Atom System Image      
  system-images;a...pis;armeabi-v7a | 5            | Google APIs ARM EABI v7a Syste...
  system-images;a...google_apis;x86 | 5            | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom Sys...
  system-images;a...ult;armeabi-v7a | 5            | ARM EABI v7a System Image        
  system-images;a...17;default;mips | 1            | MIPS System Image                
  system-images;a...-17;default;x86 | 3            | Intel x86 Atom System Image      
  system-images;a...pis;armeabi-v7a | 5            | Google APIs ARM EABI v7a Syste...
```

But if I try to install using `sdkmanager "system-images;a...ult;armeabi-v7a"`, it will not work, because I can't figure out the whole name of the available package.

Is there a way to expand the table or if there is a list online somewhere I can get the whole name of the available package?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

does this give you what you want?

```
sdkmanager --list --verbose
```

Comment: It does. An output sample using this form of the command [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44229861/1009132). I already award you the bounty because I don't consider necessary extra code for this now.

Comment: Thank you for the bounty.  I don't really think I deserve it, but I can use it!  It seems like you did most of the work figuring out how to get what you needed, but I'm glad I was able to assist in a small way.  All the best.

Answer (score 3):

**Last update:** This command works better.

> [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43435140/1009132)'s a command to
>   extract all installed android SDK packages with no garbage output:

```
find ~/.android-sdk/ -name package.xml -exec sh -c 'eval $(xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='\'localPackage\'']/@path" $0) && echo $path' {} \;
```

**Update:** Found this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460205/truncated-android-sdk-package-paths-from-sdkmanager-cli), [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37133279) and workaround:

```
(grep -Riwo -e "path.*>" ~/.android | awk -F'path="' -F'"' {'print $2'} | sort | uniq)

add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-10
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-11
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-12
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-13
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-14
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-15
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-16
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-17
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-18
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-21
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-22
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-23
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-24
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-3
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-4
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-5
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-6
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-7
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-8
add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-9
add-ons;addon-google_gdk-google-19
add-ons;addon-google_tv_addon-google-12
add-ons;addon-google_tv_addon-google-13
@android:color/black
build-tools;17.0.0
build-tools;18.0.1
build-tools;18.1.0
build-tools;18.1.1
build-tools;19.0.0
build-tools;19.0.1
build-tools;19.0.2
build-tools;19.0.3
build-tools;19.1.0
build-tools;20.0.0
build-tools;21.0.0
build-tools;21.0.1
build-tools;21.0.2
build-tools;21.1.0
build-tools;21.1.1
build-tools;21.1.2
build-tools;22.0.0
build-tools;22.0.1
build-tools;23.0.0
build-tools;23.0.1
build-tools;23.0.2
build-tools;23.0.3
build-tools;24.0.0
build-tools;24.0.1
build-tools;24.0.2
build-tools;24.0.3
build-tools;25.0.0
build-tools;25.0.1
build-tools;25.0.2
 category=
cmake;3.6.3155560
docs
emulator
extras;android;gapid;1
extras;android;gapid;3
extras;android;m2repository
extras;google;admob_ads_sdk
extras;google;analytics_sdk_v2
extras;google;auto
extras;google;gcm
extras;google;google_play_services
extras;google;google_play_services_froyo
extras;google;m2repository
extras;google;market_apk_expansion
extras;google;market_licensing
extras;google;play_billing
extras;google;simulators
extras;google;usb_driver
extras;google;webdriver
extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-alpha2
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-alpha3
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-alpha4
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-alpha5
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-alpha6
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-alpha7
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-alpha8
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-alpha9
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-beta1
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-beta2
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-beta3
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-beta4
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout;1.0.0-beta5
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-alpha2
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-alpha3
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-alpha4
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-alpha5
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-alpha6
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-alpha7
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-alpha8
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-alpha9
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-beta1
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-beta2
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-beta3
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-beta4
extras;m2repository;com;android;support;constraint;constraint-layout-solver;1.0.0-beta5
lldb;2.0
lldb;2.1
lldb;2.2
lldb;2.3
M0,0 L24,0 L24,24 L0,24 L0,0 Z
>M12,4.5C7,4.5 2.73,7.61 1,12c1.73,4.39 6,7.5 11,7.5s9.27,-3.11 11,-7.5c-1.73,-4.39 -6,-7.5 -11,-7.5zM12,17c-2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5s2.24,-5 5,-5 5,2.24 5,5 -2.24,5 -5,5zM12,9c-1.66,0 -3,1.34 -3,3s1.34,3 3,3 3,-1.34 3,-3 -1.34,-3 -3,-3z</string>
M12,7c2.76,0 5,2.24 5,5 0,0.65 -0.13,1.26 -0.36,1.83l2.92,2.92c1.51,-1.26 2.7,-2.89 3.43,-4.75 -1.73,-4.39 -6,-7.5 -11,-7.5 -1.4,0 -2.74,0.25 -3.98,0.7l2.16,2.16C10.74,7.13 11.35,7 12,7zM2,4.27l2.28,2.28 0.46,0.46C3.08,8.3 1.78,10.02 1,12c1.73,4.39 6,7.5 11,7.5 1.55,0 3.03,-0.3 4.38,-0.84l0.42,0.42L19.73,22 21,20.73 3.27,3 2,4.27zM7.53,9.8l1.55,1.55c-0.05,0.21 -0.08,0.43 -0.08,0.65 0,1.66 1.34,3 3,3 0.22,0 0.44,-0.03 0.65,-0.08l1.55,1.55c-0.67,0.33 -1.41,0.53 -2.2,0.53 -2.76,0 -5,-2.24 -5,-5 0,-0.79 0.2,-1.53 0.53,-2.2zM11.84,9.02l3.15,3.15 0.02,-0.16c0,-1.66 -1.34,-3 -3,-3l-0.17,0.01z
M20,11L7.8,11l5.6,-5.6L12,4l-8,8l8,8l1.4,-1.4L7.8,13L20,13L20,11z
>M2,4.27 L19.73,22 L22.27,19.46 L4.54,1.73 L4.54,1 L23,1 L23,23 L1,23 L1,4.27 Z</string>
>M2,4.27 L2,4.27 L4.54,1.73 L4.54,1.73 L4.54,1 L23,1 L23,23 L1,23 L1,4.27 Z</string>
>M3.27,4.27 L19.74,20.74</string>
ndk-bundle
patcher;v4
platforms;android-10
platforms;android-11
platforms;android-12
platforms;android-13
platforms;android-14
platforms;android-15
platforms;android-16
platforms;android-17
platforms;android-18
platforms;android-19
platforms;android-2
platforms;android-20
platforms;android-21
platforms;android-22
platforms;android-23
platforms;android-24
platforms;android-25
platforms;android-3
platforms;android-4
platforms;android-5
platforms;android-6
platforms;android-7
platforms;android-8
platforms;android-9
platform-tools
sources;android-14
sources;android-15
sources;android-16
sources;android-17
sources;android-18
sources;android-19
sources;android-20
sources;android-21
sources;android-22
sources;android-23
sources;android-24
sources;android-25
@string/path_password_eye
@string/path_password_eye_mask_strike_through
@string/path_password_eye_mask_visible
system-images;android-10;default;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-10;default;x86
system-images;android-10;google_apis;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-10;google_apis;x86
system-images;android-14;default;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-15;default;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-15;default;mips
system-images;android-15;default;x86
system-images;android-15;google_apis;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-15;google_apis;x86
system-images;android-16;default;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-16;default;mips
system-images;android-16;default;x86
system-images;android-16;google_apis;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-16;google_apis;x86
system-images;android-17;default;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-17;default;mips
system-images;android-17;default;x86
system-images;android-17;google_apis;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-17;google_apis;x86
system-images;android-18;default;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-18;default;x86
system-images;android-18;google_apis;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-18;google_apis;x86
system-images;android-19;default;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-19;default;x86
system-images;android-19;google_apis;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-19;google_apis;x86
system-images;android-21;android-tv;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-21;android-tv;x86
system-images;android-21;default;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-21;default;x86
system-images;android-21;default;x86_64
system-images;android-21;google_apis;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-21;google_apis;x86
system-images;android-21;google_apis;x86_64
system-images;android-22;android-tv;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-22;android-tv;x86
system-images;android-22;default;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-22;default;x86
system-images;android-22;default;x86_64
system-images;android-22;google_apis;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-22;google_apis;x86
system-images;android-22;google_apis;x86_64
system-images;android-23;android-tv;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-23;android-tv;x86
system-images;android-23;android-wear;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-23;android-wear;x86
system-images;android-23;default;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-23;default;x86
system-images;android-23;default;x86_64
system-images;android-23;google_apis;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86
system-images;android-23;google_apis;x86_64
system-images;android-24;android-tv;x86
system-images;android-24;default;arm64-v8a
system-images;android-24;default;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-24;default;x86
system-images;android-24;default;x86_64
system-images;android-24;google_apis;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-24;google_apis;x86
system-images;android-24;google_apis;x86_64
system-images;android-25;android-tv;x86
system-images;android-25;android-wear;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-25;android-wear;x86
system-images;android-25;google_apis;arm64-v8a
system-images;android-25;google_apis;armeabi-v7a
system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86
system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86_64
tools
```

> Using the last version of sdkmanager (26.0.1), sdkmanager --list
>   --verbose (an UNdocumented flag) provides the list of XML files parsed AND a (not really machine readable) list of all packages with no
>   truncation in the paths (nor the location of installed tools.

---

I don't know if the output can be customised ([related comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31886049/1009132)), but it's something they need to fix.

You can check the more common packages in this output and a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44073322/1009132).

Comment: I was hopeful about that issue tracker link, but that's not related at all

Comment: @cricket_007 check the new issue link :)

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a bit late but I also wanted to answer it because it is somehow important while developing android applications without Android Studio. You can do something like this from command line.

```
sdkmanager --list --verbose > c:\sdk-package-list.txt
```

Then check the installed and available packages. Of course your sdkmanager should be in your Path system variable.