# How can I get full package names from sdkmanager --list?

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I am trying to use the android SDK manager to install a system image. However, when I use `tools/bin/sdkmanager --list`, the output I get looks like this (truncated for brevity):

```
Available Packages:
  Path                              | Version      | Description                      
  -------                           | -------      | -------       
...
system-images;a...-15;default;x86 | 4            | Intel x86 Atom System Image      
system-images;a...pis;armeabi-v7a | 5            | Google APIs ARM EABI v7a Syste...
system-images;a...google_apis;x86 | 5            | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom Sys...
system-images;a...ult;armeabi-v7a | 4            | ARM EABI v7a System Image        
system-images;a...16;default;mips | 1            | MIPS System Image                
system-images;a...-16;default;x86 | 5            | Intel x86 Atom System Image      
system-images;a...pis;armeabi-v7a | 5            | Google APIs ARM EABI v7a Syste...
system-images;a...google_apis;x86 | 5            | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom Sys...
system-images;a...ult;armeabi-v7a | 5            | ARM EABI v7a System Image        
system-images;a...17;default;mips | 1            | MIPS System Image                
system-images;a...-17;default;x86 | 3            | Intel x86 Atom System Image      
system-images;a...pis;armeabi-v7a | 5            | Google APIs ARM EABI v7a Syste...
...
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use a path of this form to install.

```
sdkmanager system-images;a...-17;default;x86 
Failed to find package system-images;a...ult;armeabi-v7a
```

How can I get the long form of the package name so I can actually install it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android sdkmanager available packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44167152/android-sdkmanager-available-packages)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460205/truncated-android-sdk-package-paths-from-sdkmanager-cli#answer-42521077) mentioned that you can use the `--list` and `--verbose` flags combined in the newer versions of `sdkmanager` (starting with version 26.0.1).

If it helps, though, the format is basically the path relative to your `android_sdk` folder, with the slashes (`\` or `/`) replaced with semicolons.  Of course, you have to *know* what the path of something should be in order to install that particular thing...